# how to catch regex a special tag

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I am trying to catch a series of tags with regex:

```
/<shi>(\n|<shi\n>/
```

How do I match the cases below:

- `<shi>`
- `<\nshi>`
- `<\nshi\n>`
- `<shi\n\n>`
  ... (And more cases like that)

Comment: Maybe: `<(\n+)?shi(\n+)?>`?

Comment: @NNL993 it passed all my cases, thank you so much!

Comment: No problem! It also matches in cases like this: `<\n\n\nshi\n\n\n>`. :p

Comment: @NNL993 thaks you verry much

Comment: If you're trying to parse HTML or XML you're probably better of using [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString). If this is some sort of placeholder within a string template then using regex is fine.

Comment: @NNL993 An idea to use [`\n*` instead of `(\n+)?`](https://regex101.com/r/SrOrZX/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/<\n*shi\n*>/` should do the job.
Let's see why:

- `<` will match the character `<` once
- `\n*` will match the newline character between 0 and unlimited times (greedy)
- `shi` will match the characters `shi` literally (case sensitive)
- `\n*` will match the newline character between 0 and unlimited times (greedy)
- `>` will match the character `>` once

[@NNL993](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17799125/nnl993)'s answer (`<(\n+)?shi(\n+)?>`) also works, but it uses capturing groups.

- `\n` will match the newline character
- `+` will match the previous token (newline character) between one and unlimited times (greedy)
- `?` will match the previous token (`(\n+)` group) between zero and one time